# git says everything-up-to-date when pushing changes to a remote branch

Tags: git, push, git-checkout, cherry-pick

i have commits that are in a remote repository (origin/master) which i want to put in a branch created from that repository (origin/remote_branch).

when i checkout to that remote branch

```
git checkout -b mybranch origin/remote_branch
```

then cherry-picked the commits that i made

```
git cherry-pick 9df63616b0428cf6edc4261adb533a1ac516b9a0
```

git says everything-up-to-date when i try to push.

```
git push
```

is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depending on your version of Git, it may be trying to push branches with matching names, i.e., `master` to `origin/master` and `remote_branch` to `origin/remote_branch`.  If your origin repository doesn't have a branch named `mybranch` then it thinks there's nothing to update.

To override this default, you can explicitly tell git which branch to use as the source (`mybranch`) and which to use as the destination on the remote repository (`remote_branch`):

```
git push origin mybranch:remote_branch
```

There's a config option to tell git to push to remote tracking branches by default:

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

I find this more intuitive and I think it's the behavior you're looking for.  Checkout the `push.default` option in the [git config man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).  Also checkout the Examples section in the [git push man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) to see how to override the default behavior.

Comment: whoa! 

"If your origin repository doesn't have a branch named mybranch then it thinks there's nothing to update."

this totally did it! thanks for the quick reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

With a recent (2019+) version of Git, creating a branch would be done with [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) (more precise than the [confusing `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

```
git switch -c mybranch --track origin/remote_branch
```

That way, `mybranch` is automatically linked to `origin/remote_branch`, and a simple `git push` will be enough to push new `mybranch` commits to `origin/remote_branch`.